# How to map querystring and header to AWS C# lambda function parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have AWS Gateway REST API that takes 2 querystring parameters

`https://xxxxxx.xxxx.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/pets?type=dog&page=1`

The caller of the API also include `x-api-key` in the header. I want API gateway to pass querystring parameters and `x-api-key` to lambda function. So in `AWS API Gateway Console` i have configured the `Integration Request` as below

[image]

The lambda function looks like this

```
namespace AWSLambda1
{
    public class Function
    {
        public string FunctionHandler(LambdaRequest request, ILambdaContext context)
        {
            return string.Format("{0},{1},{2}", request.Type, request.Page, request.ApiKey);
        }        
    }
}

public class LambdaRequest
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Page { get; set; }
    public string ApiKey { get; set; }
}
```

**Issues**
1> When lambda function receives the request, the `Type` and `Page` properties are coming as NULL.

2>As per documentation API Gateway can map the http header using the naming convention `method.request.header.{param_name}`, however when i try to set map from as `method.request.header.x-api-key` it throws error

> Invalid mapping expression specified: Validation Result: warnings :
>   [], errors : [Invalid mapping expression parameter specified:
>   method.request.header.x-api-key]

I am not sure how do i map these query string and header to C# lambda object

*(Please note that i have already gone through [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46050894/how-to-pass-a-querystring-value-from-aws-api-gateway-to-a-lambda-c-sharp-functio) that suggest to JObject as parameter for lambda function. But it only works for me if i enable `Use Lambda Proxy integration` in `Integration Request`. In such case API gateway pass all the information to lambda. This might work for me but i am trying to avoid passing unwanted information to lambda function)*

Comment: First thing first, you need to make sure header is mapped in `Method Request` and then you can go map in `Integration Request`. The error is happening because you did not map in `Method Request` section but trying to configure it in `Integration Request`.

Answer (score 4):

Adding Full answer here.

**Header Issue**

First thing, you need to make sure header entry is added in `Method Request` and then you can go map that in `Integration Request` with mapping `method.request.header.x-api-key`. The error is happening because you did not add in `Method Request` section but trying to configure it in `Integration Request` only.

[image]
[image]

**Lambda Payload Issue**

It looks like you are not using `Lambda Proxy Integration`. If you use Lambda Proxy Integration then you will get full event JSON object event data to Lambda. Similar to answer given in [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46066004/5030709) you have shared. This JSON object will contains headers, queryparameters, path variables, url, request body etc.,. If you want to see some sample on how it looks, just go and create API Gateway Test Event on Lambda.

Now, if you do not want to use Lambda Proxy Integration but want to limit what is being sent to Lambda then you will have to create Integration Mapping Template to send only required info to Lambda such as headers, payload, query params etc., from API Gateway.

Sample Integration Template.

```
{
  "body" : $input.json('$'),
  "headers": {
    #foreach($header in $input.params().header.keySet())
    "$header": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().header.get($header))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end

    #end
  },
  "method": "$context.httpMethod",
  "params": {
    #foreach($param in $input.params().path.keySet())
    "$param": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().path.get($param))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end

    #end
  },
  "query": {
    #foreach($queryParam in $input.params().querystring.keySet())
    "$queryParam": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().querystring.get($queryParam))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end

    #end
  }  
}
```

Reference -

https://kennbrodhagen.net/2015/12/06/how-to-create-a-request-object-for-your-lambda-event-from-api-gateway/

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html

Comment: Does not look in the snapshot provided that Lambda Proxy Integration is used